# Codeigniter - get related entries

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have two tables, one that store some data like `name`, `sex` etc. end the seconds that store `images` related from the `id` of the first table.

I need to get the row of the first table and get also all the images from the second one and I would like to get them with a single query.

How can I do that? is it possibile?

I have tried with a `simple join` but I get just the first element of the second table.

Example Table 1:

```
----------------------
|ID | Name  | Sex    |
----------------------
| 1 | Chris | Male   |
----------------------
| 2 | Elisa | Female |
----------------------
```

Table 2:

```
------------------------------
| ID | User_id  | Image name |
------------------------------
| 1  | 1        | img1.jpg   |
------------------------------
| 2  | 1        | img2.jpg   |
------------------------------
| 3  | 1        | img3.jpg   |
------------------------------
| 4  | 2        | img4.jpg   |
------------------------------
```

I would like to have:

Chris, Male, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg
Elisa, Female, img4.jpg

And so on...any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    table1.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(table2.image_name SEPARATOR ', ') as image_name
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.user_id
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

**Demo** : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00932/22)

Comment: Note that GROUP_CONCAT() has a default limit of 1024 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a left outer join

```
SELECT user.*, image.image_name as image 
FROM user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN image
ON user.id = image.user_id
```

It will get all the user rows and put `empty` val in image if none was found.

Comment: this query return 3 rows with the same data, ecept for the image field

Comment: Well basically that's the goal. You can do some PHP logic in a `foreach($users as $user)` afterwards (easier to manipulate the data without concatening it).